# AMPscript: pull content from a data file without LookUp

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a data file with one row where the client will change the cells content from time to time and the automated email will pull that content at the time of every deployment.

This data file has no common columns with the subscribers list so I cannot use LookUpRows or LookUp since I cannot tie them together.

Is there any way I can get the values from this data file and assign them to variables so I can call them in the email?

Comment: Where does the 'date file' reside? On a publicly accessible URL or Enhanced FTP account? Does it contain a header row? Could you use a data file with JSON object instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another column to your data extension -- something like LookupKey -- and give it a default value of `1`.  Then in your lookup, just use that column to retrieve the row.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing that after all. It seems there is no other way around. Thanks for jumping in Adam.